# ¿ Como poner un preloader en cada página de un sitio web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy tratando de que cada una de las páginas de un sitio que estoy creando empiece con un preloader diferente.
Tengo dos funciones y por supuesto, solo carga la primera, empezando por abajo claro.
Esto hace que en la pagina donde esta la función primera, si que se desactiva el preloader transcurrido un tiempo, pero en la otra, no se desactiva ni pulsando el botón creado para desactivar el gif.
¿ Que estoy haciendo mal para que no me funcione, o quizá esto no es posible hacerlo?
Muestro los dos casos, para ver que debo corregir para conseguir que funcionen los dos gif diferentes.

La que sí que funciona:

```js
/* ----- Preloader-2 ----- */
     function mipreloaderLoad() {
        if($('.preloader2').length){
            $('.preloader2').delay(300).fadeOut(400);
        }
        $(".preloader_disabler2").on('click', function() {
            $("#preloader2").hide();
        });
    }

    /* ----- Preloader ----- */
    function preloaderLoad() {
        if($('.preloader').length){
            $('.preloader').delay(300).fadeOut(400);
        }
        $(".preloader_disabler").on('click', function() {
            $("#preloader").hide();
        });
    }
    
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        // add your functions
        preloaderLoad();
    });
```

```css
/* ---------- PRELOADER ---------- */
.preloader { 
  background-color:#ffffff; 
  background-image:url(https://ibb.co/7CJzWFt); 
  background-position:center center; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  height:100%; 
  left:0px; 
  position:fixed; 
  top:0px; 
  width:100%; 
  z-index:999999;
}
.preloader_disabler {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 43%;
  position: absolute; }


  /* ---------- PRELOADER-2 ---------- */
.preloader2 { 
  background-color:#ffffff; 
  background-image:url(https://ibb.co/PgkkRY7); 
  background-position:center center; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  height:100%; 
  left:0px; 
  position:fixed; 
  top:0px; 
  width:100%; 
  z-index:999999;
}
.preloader_disabler2 {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 43%;
  position: absolute; }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="preloader" class="preloader">
   <div id="pre" class="preloader_container">
    <div class="preloader_disabler btn btn-default">Disable Preloader</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora pongo la que no funciona:

```js
/* ----- Preloader-2 ----- */
     function preloaderLoad() {
        if($('.preloader2').length){
            $('.preloader2').delay(300).fadeOut(400);
        }
        $(".preloader_disabler2").on('click', function() {
            $("#preloader2").hide();
        });
    }

    /* ----- Preloader ----- */
    function preloaderLoad() {
        if($('.preloader').length){
            $('.preloader').delay(300).fadeOut(400);
        }
        $(".preloader_disabler").on('click', function() {
            $("#preloader").hide();
        });
    }
```

```css
/* ---------- PRELOADER ---------- */
.preloader { 
  background-color:#ffffff; 
  background-image:url(https://ibb.co/7CJzWFt); 
  background-position:center center; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  height:100%; 
  left:0px; 
  position:fixed; 
  top:0px; 
  width:100%; 
  z-index:999999;
}
.preloader_disabler {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 43%;
  position: absolute; }


  /* ---------- PRELOADER-2 ---------- */
.preloader2 { 
  background-color:#ffffff; 
  background-image:url(https://ibb.co/PgkkRY7); 
  background-position:center center; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  height:100%; 
  left:0px; 
  position:fixed; 
  top:0px; 
  width:100%; 
  z-index:999999;
}
.preloader_disabler2 {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 43%;
  position: absolute; }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
     <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="preloader2" class="preloader2">
       <div id="pre" class="preloader_container">
        <div class="preloader_disabler btn btn-default">Disable Preloader</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
      integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
Gracias.

Comment: Con preloader a que te refieres?

Comment: Hola @IvanIsayenko Lo que se muestra mientras carga la pagina, pero estoy comprobando que algo me falta por añadir, porque no funciona, no se ve el gif de la carga

Comment: Entiendo, cuando este todo puesto lo reviso!

Comment: ¿De qué forma identificas a que preloader debes llamar? Tienes dos funciones que se llaman exactamente igual, es posible que en la segunda estés ejecutando la primera y, por lo tanto, no existe el gif que quieres detener.

Comment: No se que estoy haciendo mal, que no consigo que se vea, quiza esten mal los enlaces a jQuery porque el boton no desaparece, y debería desaparecer. No se como solucionar eso para que se vea en funcionamiento y vean los errores

Comment: revisa esto: `**<script**`. Puede que sea el culpable

Comment: Gracias @Rabegi , dites con la clave, olvide llamar a la función. La cambien de nombre pero no la estaba llamando. Ahora edito, y si quieres puedes poner tu respuesta. El problema era que no estaba llamando a la segunda función

Comment: Entonces es un error tipográfico (el nombre de la función está repetido)... en mi opinión es una pregunta a cerrar

Comment: La verdad es que si, cometí un error al nombrar a la segunda función, y en el ejemplo, pero la verdad es que si @Rabegi no hubiese hecho su comentario, no me hubiese dado cuenta del error de llamar a la segunda función. Si pone una respuesta la aceptaré, pero si ven que es se puede cerrar, también lo aceptaré. En su elección queda Pablo.